# Markov/Chebychev inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

If Z is a square integrable random variable such that $E[Z]>0$, then prove that 
$$P(Z\geq k) \geq \frac{(E(Z)-k)^2}{E(Z^2)} \forall k \in [0,E(Z)]. $$

This is a homework question and I don't even understand why the inequality is reversed comparing to Markov/Chebychev inequality. Should Cauchy-Schwartz inequality be used? If yes, then how to begin? Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This a special case of the [Payley-Zygmund inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Zygmund_inequality) (whose proof can be found in the wiki article), namely if $Z$ is a non-negative random variable with finite variance and $0\leq\theta\leq 1$, then
$$
P(Z\geq \theta EZ)\geq (1-\theta)^2\frac{(EZ)^2}{EZ^2}
$$
In your case put $\theta=k/EZ$ to deduce the result.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!